# Need excel formula for the below question

Tags: excel-formula

Create a formula that returns only the characters that appear after "X" for the given character strings. The same formula must work for the whole column!

Example of how it should look like after you apply your formula:

765892X329  329
752238X44   44

Answer (score 3):

Here’s one that works:

```
=REPLACE(A1, 1, SEARCH("X", A1), "")
```

It first finds where the X is in the cell and replaces all the text from the beginning up to where X is with nothing, in other words removing it, leaving you with just the text after X.

Replace both the A1 in the above formula with the cell position you want to apply the formula to.

Comment: Nice approach. I was thinking in the direction of RIGHT/ FIND +1 or MID / FIND +1 / LEN. , but yours is cleaner